# checkbox inside an update panel does not get its state

Tags: jquery

I have 2 checkboxes inside an Updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkboxDivE"/>
    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkboxDivE"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in js, jquery:

```
$('.checkboxDivE').live('click', function (e) {

   alert($(this).is(':checked')); // always giving false result

});
```

markup:

```
<span class="checkboxDivE" title="Export a trip"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_Trips_ctl02_checkboxDivE" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_Trips$ctl02$checkboxDivE"></span>

<span class="checkboxDivE" title="Export a trip"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_Trips_ctl03_checkboxDivE" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_Trips$ctl03$checkboxDivE"></span>
```

Whenever I check or uncheck the checkbox, the result is always false?

I have spent hours for finding a solution but I could not! is it a problem with jquery inside an updatePanel?

Comment: You should post the markup that is on the browser rather than the server side one. The ASP.NET CheckBox does not render the CssClass on the html checkbox input, but rather to a span that comprises it (if I remember right) and your selector is not able to get to the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your markup, you'll notice that the ID of your checkbox is actually `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_Trips_ctl03_CheckBoxExportTour` and the class you are trying to grab - `checkboxDivE` - belongs to the span.

You just need to change your selector.

Comment: no, I renamed the div when posting on this post. it is fine with the selector. It showed the alert popup each time I clicked

Comment: @devn - I don't think you understand what I was saying. You are selecting your span with your selector - not the checkbox. So, when you click the checkbox, you are ALSO clicking the span. This is why you still get the pop-up, but it will never say true. See an example of this here - http://jsfiddle.net/fvVAy/2/

Answer (score 0):

It should be used like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fvVAy/

Maybe you're using a class selector where you should be using a name selector. If the jsfiddle doesn't help, try uploading checkbox markup.

Comment: turns out you were selecting the <span>, not it's child <input> try changing the selector to '.checkboxDivE input' as illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvVAy/3/

Comment: Also, if you want the "whole span" to be clickable, you can have it so that when you (a) click the span, (b) the child input's value will be reported. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvVAy/4/